# See thine self through its misty cover / and thy will see naught within it... What is it?

Tags: riddle

> See thine self through its misty cover 
>   and thou wilt see naught within it. 
>   See the floor through what it has uncovered 
>   and thy will see it naught it all. 
>   It's ate 'twixt the bookends of wire and lover
>   though not 'twixt those of ire and love.
>   Work fast, work hard--it is thy reward.
>   Though thine self is naught but it.

What is *it*?

Hints:

> 'Twixt means between
> All mentions of 'it' are referring to the object you are trying to guess
> The number seven.
> There is a grammatical error that is made on purpose. Knowing this might help you.

Comment: Title, error or clue?

Comment: Should be "thou will" (or "thou wilt"), not "thy will", but I don't see how that might help as a clue...?

Comment: @Hellion Oh XD I didn't intend that mistake. Good eye! The mistake is on line 5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> Water?

See thine self through its misty cover
and thy will see naught within it.

> If you see your reflection on the surface of the water (also mist is water vapour), then the water is clear and has nothing in it.

See the floor through what it has uncovered 
and thy will see it naught it all.

> When the bottom of a (former) body of water has been uncovered, the water has been drained away?

It's ate 'twixt the bookends of wire and lover
though not 'twixt those of ire and love.

> It is "ate" between "w" and "r".

Work fast, work hard--it is thy reward.
Though thine self is naught but it.

> You sweat when you work fast and hard, and your body is mostly water.

Comment: _C'est parfait!_ (that is, perfect!)

Comment: What does seven have to do with it?

Comment: Water has a PH of 7.